# EF Core asynchronous complex queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been researching how to do a group-by clause in my LINQ query and found that it's only possible if you execute the GroupBy on the client side. Reading MS's article on complex queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators, it seems possible to achieve server-side grouping (evident by the SQL statement the group example generated). However, I'm unable to find if the complex queries can be executed asynchronously. Or rather, are they executed asynchronously.

Does anyone know if complex queries execute asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

The synchronous or asynchronous execution isn't based on the complexity of the query. It's based on which finalizing method you use to consume the results. If you use [`query.ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-5.0) it'll be asynchronous. If you use `query.ToList()` it's synchronous.